# How to push stream to AWS Elemental MediaLive Inputs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront, live-streaming, flashmedialiveencoder

I have set up my streaming using MediaLive and MediaPackage and the problem is I don't know how to do RTP_PUSH?

[image: See this photo]

Answer (score 3):

You can use ffmpeg to send stream to AWS MediaLive RTP_Push input. See this sample command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i mySourceFile.ts -c copy -map 0 -f rtp_mpegts -fec prompeg=l=5:d=20
rtp://35.XX.XX.XX:5000
```

[Details for command params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsCR5.jpg)

For more details refer to this [document](https://d1.awsstatic.com/awselemental/workflowexamples/Workflow3_Example_FFMPEG_RTP_to_MediaLive_and_MediaPackage.pdf) from AWS blog.

Answer (score 2):

AWS has published a few guides that should help you get started on contributing your video content into MediaLive.

Here is a guide if you have an AWS Elemental Live apppliance: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/connecting-aws-elemental-live-on-premises-to-aws-media-services-in-the-cloud/

Here is a guide if you'd like to connect to MediaLive from FFMPEG: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/connecting-ffmpeg-using-rtp-to-aws-media-services-in-the-cloud/

The MediaLive documentation also contains more information about using RTP inputs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/rtp-push-input.html

Comment: It's better to include the relevant specific content from links rather than just point users to the whole thing. It speeds up getting to the gist of your answer and guards against the links dying.

Comment: Hi, Thank you Greg
This is very helpful but not for my case, I really hope there is another way using NGINX.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use OBS https://obsproject.com/.

You can set up any video you want or capture your entire screen.

To set up stream:

1. Open Settings;
2. Open Stream tab;
3. Put your RTP URL;
4. Set key and close Settings;
5. Push button "Start Streaming"